# Initializing multidimensial array with unknown size array elements gives error

Tags: c, eclipse, multidimensional-array

```
char list_ch[][2] = {
         'a', 'A',
         'b', 'B',
         'c', 'C',
         'd', 'D',
         'e', 'E',
         'f', 'F',
         'g', 'G'};
```

According to [this](http://aelinik.free.fr/c/ch12.htm) tutorial I'm following, this is supposed to create a multidimensional array with 7 elements each containing two other elements that are of type character.

However, using eclipse I get this error:

```
(near initialization for ‘list_ch[0]’) [-Wmissing-braces]   HelloWorld.c    /HelloWorld line 73 C/C++ Problem
```

Why is this happening? Is it my compiler that is causing the issue or is it invalid syntax?

Comment: You haven't posted the **essence** of the error message. (Yes, in this particular case, it's easy to guess what's wrong, but still...)

Comment: It's not an error, is it? It looks like a warning.

Comment: @h2CO3 thats all I get to see in the error tab

Comment: @KerrekSB in my IDE it says its an error

Comment: Do you have `-Werror` set?

Comment: @user1534664 Scroll down (or up)...

Comment: @CarlNorum what is `-Werror`

Comment: @user1534664: that transfors errors into warnings. Makes your compiler stricter, which is a Good Thing (TM). (also, seriously, you SHOULD HAVE GOOGLED THAT!!).

Comment: @CarlNorum: thanks for doing the right thing!

Comment: @ haylem two users simultaneously posting answers is not a punishable offense. You can only downvote for good reasons. Punishing people for being seconds slow just teaches them to stay away from contributing. @CarlNorum could have decided to remove the answer or leave it, and the community would reward the most useful answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a warning, because you should write like this instead:

```
char list_ch[][2] = {
         {'a', 'A'},
         {'b', 'B'},
         {'c', 'C'},
         {'d', 'D'},
         {'e', 'E'},
         {'f', 'F'},
         {'g', 'G'}};
```

Comment: In the link it shows two ways of doing it, this and the way I did it.

Comment: @H2CO3: And it worked nicely, and that's a good thing to avoid questions with many duplicate answers. Thanks a lot to CarlNorum for being ego-less and doing the right thing. It's part of the game. I prefer my SO searches to end up on pages with either multipe answers providing different valid bits of information or a single canonical one. Downvotes are meant to seriously reduce, or, in this case, even suppress noise. This wasn't meant to be aggressive, and I hope I didn't offend him (and thank him again for reacting brilliantly).

Comment: @CarlNorum: And yes, it's also a strange crowd experiment, how initial votes can bias following voters, isn't it? :) And sometimes it **is** infuriating when your answer is actually **better** but because you posted it later (or even earlier for that matter), but another one got voted first and then "catches a wave"... Amusing how you can replicate crowd behavior models and game theories on SE sites... :)

Comment: @haylem You **did** offend him (and your childish behavior even disturbs me). Carl Norum's last comment was "I guess you've never heard of caching..." - I assume he didn't want to start a debate with someone not eligible for it (to phrase it as gently as possible), and neither do I.

Comment: @H2CO3: Ok. I was a bit afraid of that, but on the other hand that's clearly what the site's guidelines recommend, except if I misread something. My apologies, then.

Comment: @haylem You didn't misread anything - you were just **assuming** that he was trying to repwhore the question which he wasn't. Quite obviously, he didn't see the first answer posted at the time he was writing his own one - that happens more than often here, and there's no need to be nitpicky about it. What you've done is basically trolling, at best.

Comment: @H2CO3: What? No I wasn't assuming any such thing. I really thought he just typed his answer at almost the same time as Joachim. I just found it fair that Joachim got the vote for the canonical answer as they were identical and he was first. That's all. I know it happens all the time, I even said it above. I think you are making assumptions on my part. Anyways, if you feel like discuss this further, we can do it in chat (though I don't think that'd bring anything).